# Load all constraints into Linear Programming object - lpSolveAPI

Tags: r, linear-programming, lpsolve

Hello and thanks in advance.  I'm using the package `lpSolveAPI` to solve a linear programming problem.  When I create my Linear Programming object then add my constraints, I'm iterating through all the rows in my constraint matrix `mat` and adding constraints separately.  The example [here](http://www.icesi.edu.co/CRAN/web/packages/lpSolveAPI/vignettes/lpSolveAPI.pdf) seems to do the same except by setting columns.  Must I add each constraint separately? Or is there a way to just attach the entire constraint matrix, direction vector and right-hand-side vectors at once?

```
  #Generate Linear Programming Object
  lprec <- make.lp(nrow = nrow(mat) # Number of Constraints
                   , ncol = ncol(mat) # Number of Decision Variables
  )


  #Set Objective Function to Minimize
  set.objfn(lprec, obj)

  #Adding Constraints Separately
  #Note Direction is included along with Constraint Value
  for(i in 1:nrow(mat) ){
    add.constraint(lprec,mat[i,], dir[i], rhs[i])
    print(i)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

lpSolveAPI doesn't allow this but you can use lpsove which is another package/interface to Lp_solve.

```
lprec <- lp(const.mat=mat, ...)
```

In the same way, direction and objective can be submitted as vectors using `const.dir` and `objective` parameters.